# Translation of "I see"

Tags: oral

> A: Are you going to the party this evening.
>
> B: No, I don't think so.
>
> A: I see.

What is the appropriate translation of "I see"?

> A: Est-ce que tu vas aller à la fête ce soir?
>
> B: Non, je ne pense pas.
>
> A: ___

Is it *Je vois*, *Je comprends*, *Bon*, or something else?

Comment: The three options seem all fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would translate by

> A : Je vois.

In wiktionary [2.1 see meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see#Verb) :

> - 2. To form a mental picture of.
>
>      1. (figuratively) To understand.
>
>         > *Do you see what I mean?‎*

Answer (score 0):

I use "d'accord" and "bon" often for this context, with some accent and facial expression.